# how to create autoload under vendor directory for php rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq, composer-php

I m new to php and rabbitmq in debian(Linux). I have installed xampp, rabbitmq and also installed composer.phar in project directory using below command

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/rabbitmq_demo# curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | /opt/lampp/bin/php
```

Now I use Composer to install the dependencies of the project using below command

```
composer.phar install
```

but it thrown an error as below

```
bash: php: command not found
```

I have preferred the link https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

I want to prepare autoload.php
Please help me to create autoload under vendor directory.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a php cli program installed on your computer or it is not in your current `$PATH` variable. Please install PHP first or correct your `$PATH` environment variable.

Once you have this, run the `composer.phar install` again. This will download all dependencies listed  in your `composer.json` file. Once the program completes, you will have a file ``vendor/autoload.php`. You can just require this file at the beginning of your own script and everything will be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the PHP command line (CLI) in the XAMPP install, to your bash environment. (You'd think the installer would do this!)

The XAMPP PHP CLI on Debian is at `/opt/lampp/bin/php`

So you need to add `/opt/lampp/bin` to your $PATH environment variable.

See [this answer for the various options in modifying your path](https://serverfault.com/questions/166383/how-set-path-for-all-users-in-debian) depending on who you want to be able to run PHP.

- /etc/login.defs
- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile
- ~/.bashrc

In one of those files, you append to the path thus:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

and re-login.